# Finding $2^{2^n}$ mod $m$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is there any special technique for finding $2^{2^n} \pmod m$?

Taking $n$ and $m$ to be very high. Approx till $10^4$

Comment: If $m$ is odd, you can reduce the exponent $2^n$ mod $\phi(m)$.

Comment: What is $ϕ(m)$ here?

Comment: It's the Euler phi totient function

Comment: And how can I find that ?